# Composer - installing dependency from private git repository

Tags: composer-php

I have two projects on a private GitHub account - one is a library, and the other my application.

I want to include my library into my application.

My library's composer.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "andyw/mylibrary",
  "description": "My Library",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/andyw/mylibrary",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.0",
    "monolog/monolog": "1.*",
    "guzzle/guzzle": "3.*",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.*",
    "nixilla/twitter-api-consumer": "*",
    "webignition/robots-txt-file": "dev-master",
    "webignition/robots-txt-parser": "dev-master",
    "pusher/pusher-php-server": "*",
    "symfony/validator": "2.*"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.*"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
      "": "src/"
    }
  }
}
```

Running `composer update` on that project installs the dependencies just fine.  So far, so good.

Now this is my application's composer.json:

```
{
  "name": "andyw/myapp",
  "type": "project",
  "description": "My application",

  "homepage": "https://github.com/andyw/myapplication",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "git@github.com:andyw/myapplication.git"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.0",
    "andyw/mylibrary": "dev-master",
    "facebook/php-sdk-v4": "4.0.*",
    "silex/silex": "~1.1",
    "monolog/monolog": "~1.6",
    "twig/twig": "~1.14",
    "doctrine/dbal": "~2.4",
    "nesbot/Carbon": "~1.6",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.*",
    "jms/serializer": "0.15",
    "symfony/validator": "2.*",
    "jdesrosiers/silex-cors-provider": "~0.1.2",
    "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": ">=4.1.2,<4.2-dev",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "mockery/mockery": "~0.8.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
      "App": "src/"
    }
  }
}
```

Running `composer update` on that project fails.  Adding the `--verbose` flag gives this output:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for andyw/mylibrary dev-master -> satisfiable by andyw/mylibrary[dev-master].
    - andyw/mylibrary dev-master requires webignition/robots-txt-file dev-master -> no matching package found.
```

If mylibrary can install `webignition/robots-txt-file dev-master`, why can't it be installed as a dependency of a dependency?  How can I fix this?

FYI: None of my repos are public and I've changed the names of my packages/files for privacy reasons.

Comment: add `"minimum-stability": "dev"` flag and try.

Comment: Thanks - that did work, but it seemed to pull down the dev versions of all our other dependencies, which probably isn't ideal.

Comment: You have not specified the version for some of the libraries. See `dev-master`. `dev-master` is always recognized by composer as development. Alternatively you can specify the version and download.

Comment: @naxtek Did you manage this issue ?

Comment: You should also add `"prefer-stable": true` if you prefer stable over development versions.

Answer (score 1):

Never never never never depend on branches! Always use a tagged version. This is the most important rule when using Composer.

Branches are moving targets. If anyone commits something new, this will move the pointer to the software's state that you were using, and you cannot easily find this state again. Also, branches are considered development-stability, and the only package that can set stability is the root application package. Libraries that depend on other packages in dev stability are a very bad idea because they force the root application to explicitly allow development stability.

This is extremely bad in the long run. It will make your software unmaintainable to the point where using Composer will always fail, break stuff, and you start wondering why everyone keeps using it (hint: they are not depending on branches).

Now here's the thing:

webignition/robots-txt-file has tagged versions: 0.1 and 0.2, and the 0.2 is exactly at the same commit as the master branch. Just use that!

The same is true for webignition/robots-txt-parser, but here you have version 1.0, 1.0.1 and 1.0.2, and the master branch is exactly version 1.0.2.

You should be able to simply update to these versions. If that does not work because your software relies on an older version of the master branch, you are experiencing the exact problem when depending on branches: Your library told me that dev-master is ok, and when I look at the packages' repo, dev-master is version 0.2 or 1.0.2 respectively, and I'd expect it to work. If you do explicitly point to something like 0.1 and 1.0.1, this is unlikely to change over time and will always be a working combination.

Note that it is a good idea to check if the external package developers use semantic versioning, and then use an appropriate wildcard selector for a version range. Allowing some slack in versions will make multiple packages depending on the same third package to agree on a common version easier.